# convert json string into two dimensional bool array

Tags: c#, arrays, json

Does anyone know how to convert a string which contains JSON into a c# 2D array. I have this which reads the text/json from a web Browser and stores it into a string.

```
 "BoolArry": [
               [ true, true, false, ... ],
               [ true, true, true, ...],
               ...,
               [ true, false, false, ... ]
             ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JavaScript serializer provided by .Net: [JavaScriptSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (use `using System.Web.Script.Serialization;`)

```
var boolArrayStr =
    @"[
        [ true, true, true ],
        [ true, true, false ],
        [ true, false, false ],
        [ false, false, false ],
    ]";

JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();

bool[][] boolArrays = jss.Deserialize<bool[][]>(boolArrayStr);

foreach (bool[] array in boolArrays)
{
    foreach (bool val in array)
    {
        Console.Write(val);
        Console.Write(" ");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

Output is:

```
True True True
True True False
True False False
False False False
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote Json to file (D:\Temp\text.txt):

```
[
  [ true, true, false ],
  [ true, true, true ],
  [ true, false, false ]
]
```

You can read this as `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray` and convert as you wish:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText(@"D:\Temp\text.txt")) as Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray;
var arr = (from e in obj select e.Values<bool>().ToArray()).ToArray();
```

`arr` is of type `bool[][]` (array of arrays)

Usage:

```
bool value = arr[x][y];
```